# Calculating Distance on Combined Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT Distinct(Venue_Name), Count(*) as `num1` 
FROM venuetagview 
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT Tag,COUNT(*) AS `num` 
FROM usertags 
WHERE UserID=4
GROUP BY Tag 
ORDER BY `num` DESC
) as a 
ON venuetagview.Tag=a.Tag 
GROUP BY Venue_Name 
ORDER BY `num1` DESC
```

And I am trying to add a 'distance' calculation into it, using the latitude/longitude I have in the venuetagview table. I have tried this:

```
SELECT  
  ( 6371 
  * acos( cos( radians(51.529099) ) 
  * cos( radians( Venue_Latitude ) ) 
  * cos( radians( Venue_Longitude ) 
  - radians(-0.084981) ) 
  + sin( radians(51.529099) ) 
  * sin( radians( Venue_Latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance, 
Distinct(Venue_Name), 
Count(*) as `num1` 
FROM venuetagview 
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT Tag,
COUNT(*) AS `num` 
FROM usertags 
WHERE UserID=4
GROUP BY Tag 
ORDER BY `num` DESC
) as a 
ON venuetagview.Tag=a.Tag 
GROUP BY Venue_Name 
ORDER BY `num1` DESC
```

However I am getting an error using this.

Comment: Please note that DISTINCT is not a function. Further, I suspect its removal will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Only issue I see with your posted query is

1. `distinct` is keywork and should be used like `distinct column_name`

   `SELECT Distinct (Venue_Name)` should just be `SELECT Venue_Name` or 
   `SELECT Distinct Venue_Name`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Strawberry removing DISTINCT solved this:

`SELECT

( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(51.529099) ) 
* cos( radians( Venue_Latitude ) ) 
* cos( radians( Venue_Longitude ) 
- radians(-0.084981) ) 
+ sin( radians(51.529099) ) 
* sin( radians( Venue_Latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance, 
Venue_Name, 
Count(*) as`num1
`FROM venuetagview 
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT Tag,
COUNT(*) AS`num
`FROM usertags 
WHERE UserID=4
GROUP BY Tag 
ORDER BY`num`DESC) as a 
ON venuetagview.Tag=a.Tag 
GROUP BY Venue_Name 
ORDER BY distance ASC`